# ' Ė ' Character cannot insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8

Cannot insert french words into database.

```
<?php  


Class Row{

    private $db = NULL;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = $this->connect();

    }

    private function connect(){
        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/../config/globalconfig.php";
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . ";", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $db;
    }

    public function insert(){

        $sql  = "INSERT INTO reservation (userId,workingDay,vehicleId,customerId,beginTime,endTime,beginTimeActual,endTimeActual,finalCustomer,phone, mobile,floor,address,zipCodeId,info,paymentModeId,price,kilometerNbr,price_total_ttc,price_received,status,infoSystem, isNote, no_email, no_gsm, owner_id_company_profile, multiday_reservation, parent_res_id, res_endDate,originalCreater) 
        VALUES ('54','2020-02-10','10','60546','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','test data','78956855','','1','Rue des Ėtudiants 28, Saint-Gilles, Belgium','8257','','2','0.00','0','0','0','planned','', '0', '0', '0','1', '0', '0','2020-01-10' ,'54' )";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt->Execute();

    }

    private function returnId(){

    }


}



$Row = new Row();

var_dump($Row->insert());
```

?

> ERROR :  Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column ...

After remove ' Ė ' character from insert query , it's worked fine.

**I alread tried utf8 encode method , htmlentities methods**

Comment: I would suggest using prepared statements to prevent quoting issues. Since you're using PDO, take advantage of [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

Comment: That alone will probably not solve any underlying encoding issues though, so you should probably have a good read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through first of all as well.

Comment: i used bind method, it's still same

Comment: Have you tried $mysqli->real_escape_string ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini using prepared statements and parameters would be far preferable to doing that, for multiple reasons. Although in this example all the data is hard-coded so neither real_escape_string or parameterisation would solve anything.

Comment: Please paste your SQL structure and show us you country/encoding/language settings. Are you shure your datetime-format ist YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: Are you ***very** sure* that the list of inserted values actually corresponds to the list of fields?  It sure sounds suspicious to me that SQL says "invalid *DATETIME* format!"

Comment: Huh?  What is `Ė` doing in a date??  See "best practice" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: @RickJames I'm sure the problem is not the `Ė`. @CharmathViranga please try  to replace the `Ė` by a `E`. I expect that the error is the same.

Comment: @h.m.i.13 when i replace Ė with E it's perfectly fine

Comment: ok, so I was wrong. It's very strange. There are two dates in the statement `workingDay` and `res_endDate`. You posted only the beginning of the error message. Witch column is stated in the error message?

Comment: @h.m.i.13 Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x96tudi...' for column `localift_dump`.`reservation`.`address` at row 1 in /Applications/dev/project/test.php:153 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/dev/project/test.php(153): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /Applications/dev/project/test.php(168): Row->insert() #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/dev/project/test.php on line 153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address column has **cp1252 west european** encode. It changed to **utf8mb4**. Now its working fine.

For extra information refer this external link

https://www.eversql.com/mysql-utf8-vs-utf8mb4-whats-the-difference-between-utf8-and-utf8mb4/